# Convert Base64 string to audio file in swift

Tags: swift, xml, base64, nsdata, localdb

I received a base64 string(string is too long) from the XML parsing which I want to convert into an audio file and I do write that base64 string converting into the NSData and successfully write in the document directory but when I get back that audio file it is not playing. Is anyone faced this?

```
 func getPackages() {
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore (value: 0)
        let parameters = "<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">\n  <soap12:Body>\n    <GetPackage xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n      <data>\n        <UID>123</UID>\n        <Platform>iOS</Platform>\n        <PackageCode>UA</PackageCode>\n      </data>\n    </GetPackage>\n  </soap12:Body>\n</soap12:Envelope>"
        let postData = parameters.data(using: .utf8)
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.cool-english.info/Service.asmx?wsdl")!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
        request.addValue("application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = postData
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else {
                print(String(describing: error))
                return
            }
            let parser = XMLParser(data: data)
            parser.delegate = self
            parser.parse()
            semaphore.signal()
        }
        task.resume()
        semaphore.wait()
    }
```

//XML parsing delegate

```
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        let data = string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
        if (!data.isEmpty) {
            if currentParsingElement == "GetPackageResult" {
                packageResult += data
                self.saveBase64StringToAudio(packageResult)
            }
        }
    }
```

//For writing in the document directory

```
func saveBase64StringToAudio(_ base64String: String) {

        guard
            var documentsURL = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last,
            let convertedData = Data(base64Encoded: base64String)
            else {
            //handle error when getting documents URL
            return
        }

        //name your file however you prefer0
        documentsURL.appendPathComponent("audio.mp3")
        do {
            try convertedData.write(to: documentsURL)            
            do {
                audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: documentsURL)
                guard let player = audioPlayer else { return }
                player.play()
            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } catch {
            //handle write error here
        }
        print(documentsURL)
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I am also looking for synthesising a string into an audio file. I was wondering if you actually solved your issue.

Comment: Hello @bellotas, yes I had solved the issue by replacing "audio.mp3" with "audio.zip".

Comment: Understood. As I got it, this method synthesises a string into an audio file which can be played. Am i right?

Comment: yes right, I got an audio.zip file but for an audio play, I did the file unzip process(using SSZipArchive library) after that I can able to play audio.

Comment: Nice, just wondering... Is there any particular reason to create a zip file and then unzip it? What I mean is, is it not possible to create the mp3 directly?

Comment: Yes, because there are multiple mp3 files as a package not single, here I asked for only one package code(you can see in parameter) but in the scenario, there are multiple packages with multiple audio files that's why.